# FQL - querying photo table returning empty set

Tags: facebook-fql, fbconnect

I'm having a problem retrieving any data from the photo table.

I have been able to query the album and user tables successfully, but when I query photo, it returns an empty set. This is the query I have been using:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner=ownerID
```

My application currently has the following permissions:

- read_stream
- offline_access
- publish_stream
- user_photos
- user_status

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never got this query to work but I did manage to get some sort of result from querying this table.

After I upload a photo by posting to "me/photos" using the Graph API the response received is the "object_id" for the photo that has just been posted. So I created the following query:

```
SELECT link FROM photo WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID_RECEIVED
```

If I get the owner for that photo, it's the same one I had been using in my previous query and I still have no idea why it's not working. But at least I can achieve what I need to do with this new one.